# Requirements for a personal project

Tags: requirements

Gathering requirements is an essential stage creating software or web applications. 
I have searched the web extensively without finding any directions on how to elicit requirements for personal projects. All information i found - including books i read - is focussing on different stakeholders.

So i´m wondering, what would be the best way to 'gather' the requirements for personal projects?

I can't imagine i'm the only one with this question. I have plenty of ideas for webapplications. Since i am the only stakeholder at this time - no users are identified yet, i need to develop a couple of applications for personal use - i find it hard to interview my self to elicit those requirements.

As English is not my native language, apologies for possible textual errors.

Comment: IIRC the requirements documents mainly exist so you understand what the stakeholders want, and everyone on the team knows them too. If you're the only stakeholder and the only developer, they seem rather irrelevant.

Comment: @Tom: I understand your point of view, but i don't agree. In my opinion requirements documents are guidelines for developing to make sure you develop what is needed and which parts have priority. It doesn't matter for who it is programmed. It doesn't matter how big the developing team is. If you are the only stakeholder, you can't do everything from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a document with all the information you have in your head of the project in a bullet list format called "Project Memoir". Just list all the information & business rules you need to put in the project. You can after that start developing a kind of informal Software 
requirements document (as it's for a personal project) containing some essential information for you in the development phase, like a feature list with their description, use cases & scenarios that will help you in testing in later phase, mock up screens for defining the UI look & elements, data elements lists for defining screen contents. Just keep it simple & easy as it's for only your personal use.
Hope that would help :)

Comment: Thanks. It's a good suggestion to create the document in a step by step way.

Answer (score 0):

The questions are supposed to be a trigger of a thought process.

What makes it any different in case you are the developer next to the stakeholder? Your thoughts are those of a stakeholder and you will have to try to identify your own requirements by this process.

Identifying your own requirements with a structured approach will help you identifying requirements that you would otherwise have encountered during development.

If the sole purpose is not only personal, I doubt whether it is a good idea to start developing. Then you will need to find prospects to interview. Investigate the possible markets.